# Validate if input string is a number between 0-255 using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am facing problem while matching input string with Regex. I want to validate input number is between 0-255 and length should be up to 3 characters long. code is working fine but when I input 000000 up to any length is shows true instead false.

Here is my code :-

```
String IP = "000000000000000";
        System.out.println(IP.matches("(0*(?:[0-9][0-9]?|[0-2][0-5][0-5]))"));
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this using regular expressions?

Comment: If you need leading zeros, try this:
`"((\\d{1,2}|[01]\\d{1,2}|[0-2][0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}(\\d{1,2}|[01]\\d{1,2}|[0-2][0-4]\\d|25[0-5])"`

Comment: Why would you want to execute about a megabyte of regex code instead of a simple conversion to binary and then a single comparison operator?

Comment: One ends up needing to define regexps like this because one is using someone else's bonkers idea of how to implement an IP filter. I'm looking at you, Micronaut Security!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
boolean valid = IP.matches("^(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$");

// since .matches expects complete match you can omit anchors
boolean valid = IP.matches("(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU3gC3/223)

Comment: Thanks anubhava. It's working perfect now. Also can you suggest me better source to learn regex beyond the basics.

Comment: I am a big fan of http://www.regular-expressions.info and for Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Just a little bit addition: You could make your regexp 1 tag shorter by adding 1? front of your 2 digit match, as 0-99/ 100 -199 only an optional 1 is the difference, and you could take out the 1[0-9]{2} part

Comment: Thanks @zolo yes `\b(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b` will a bit smaller (edited)

Comment: As shown in the demo link, this pattern (I assume incorrectly) matches two-digit numbers that have a leading zero like: `01` and `09`.

Comment: Your new adjusted pattern doesn't match `0`.  I am not challenging you on this to be rude, I am waiting for you to pull a regex rabbit out of a hat and show me something crazy awesome that I've never considered. [respect]

Comment: @mickmackusa: Use this one: `\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b`

Comment: How about we accept all leading 0's too: \b0*(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\b and then if you want to verify a valid IPv4 address you can use the following:
(?:0*(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){1,3}0*(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]) *** ( Remember 127.1 is the same as 127.0.0.1 so 127.1 is a valid IP address ) ***

Comment: so with @zolo's suggestion (`(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])`) the regex is less strict as pointed by @mickmackusa and allows two-digit numbers that have leading zeros. @anubhava's alternate solution `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` will provide a stricter regex which doesn't allow two-digit numbers with leading zeros.

Comment: @anubhava this did not work for `000` , I have modified your regex as below to support this  `\\b([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\b`

Comment: Just change `1?[0-9]{1,2}` to `[0-9]{1,3}` to allow `000`

Comment: @anubhava, your approach says this is valid IP:  'asdf1.1.dd1.dd1'

Comment: No it doesn't. Regex in `.matches` is automatically anchored so it effectively becomes `^(?:1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$` and that won't match.

Answer (score 15):

Tested this:

```
static String pattern = "^(([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]){1}$";
```

It works for the following:

- IP Addresses xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx / xx.xx.xx.xx / x.x.x.x / mix of these.
- Leading zeros are allowed.
- Range 0-255 / maximum 3 digts.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this pattern which matches `"0"`, `"1"`, ... `"255"`:

```
"([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
```

[Demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/9BUleT)

Comment: You are correct mentioning each case, however you can simplify it. 0-199 you could check with one section, 200-249 the other, 250-255 is the third one. Shorter, more simple, and faster.

Comment: I found this solution at https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html with much more in-depth explanation. Also, you could shorten this regex to `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` as can be seen by @anubhava's alternate solution. Basically, you are replacing `1[0-9][0-9]` with `1[0-9]{2}`.

Comment: This pattern is more appropriate because it also avoids "00" compared to the accepted pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Using boundary tags to ensure only (0 to 255) numbers is matched, the optimized pattern that I have to offer is:

```
\b(?:1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|[1-9]?\d|25[0-5])\b
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EnVQF2/1) (in PHP/PCRE to show step count)

**4010 steps** when checking a list from `0` to `256`.

This pattern will not match `01` or `001`. (no match on one or more leading zeros)

Considerations:

1. Use quantifiers on consecutive duplicate characters.
2. Organize the alternatives not in sequential order (*single-digit, double-digit, 100's, under-249, 250-255*) but with quickest mis-matches first.
3. Avoid non-essential capture (or non-capture) groups. (despite seeming logical to condense the "two hundreds" portion of the pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
"^(((\d|0\d|00\d|\d{2}|0\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|2[0-5]{2})\.){3})(\d|0\d|00\d|\d{2}|0\d{2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|2[0-5]{2})$"
```

It works also with leading zeroes

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean valid = IP.matches("(0?[0-9]{1,2}|1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])");
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete ip inet4 match :

JS

```
/(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])/g.exec(myIp);
```

https://regex101.com/r/tU3gC3/12

Minified :

```
/(1?(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])/g.exec(myIp);
```

https://regex101.com/r/tU3gC3/13

Answer (score 0):

This will work for following pattern and ip containing initial zeros
e.g: 023.45.12.56

```
pattern=(\\d{1,2}|(0|1)\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need leading zeros, try this:

```
"((\\d{1,2}|[01]\\d{1,2}|[0-2][0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}(\\d{1,2}|[01]\\d{1,2}|[0-2][0-4]\\d|25[0-5])"
```

It satisfies following conditions: IP address is a string in the form "A.B.C.D", where the value of A, B, C, and D may range from 0 to 255. Leading zeros are allowed. The length of A, B, C, or D can't be greater than 3.

Maybe somebody can help with additional simplifying?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate ip4 with 'ip/mask', so regex looks like this:

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$
```

Just ip

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

JS code to test it

```
function isMatchByRegexp(stringToValidate, regexp) {
var re = new RegExp(regexp);
return re.test(stringToValidate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(2[0-4][0-9])|([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])

To match 0 to 249 specifically

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by thinking in four conditions that might happen

```
 String zeroTo255 = "((0|1)\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]|\\d{1,2})";
 String validIpPattern = zeroTo255 + "\\." + zeroTo255 + "\\." + zeroTo255 + "\\." + zeroTo255;
```

1. (0|1)\d{2} catches any three digit number starting with 0 or 1.
2. 2[0-4]\d catches numbers between 200 and 249.
3. 25[0-5] catches numbers between 250 and 255.
4. \d{1,2} catches any one or two digit number

you can test it in https://regexr.com/

To test it here in [regexr](https://regexr.com/) you need to remove one backslash

> (\\d --> \d)

```
((0|1)\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|\d{1,2})
```

> Note that \d represents digits in regular expressions, same as [0-9]