# Regex based search and replace in vscode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In VSCode: I would like to do a wildcard replace of:

```
rgb(1, 1, 1 ,1)
```

with:

```
rgba(1, 1,1 ,1)
```

Essentially when an alpha value is specified, the datatype should be changed from "rgb" to "rgba".
Where alpha is not specified e.g rgb(1,1,1) - they should remain unchanged.

I tried:

Find: `rgb(.*,.*,.*,.*)`
Replace: `rgba($1)`

which obviously did not work. What would be the correct regex syntax to achieve this? Thank you.

Update: Please note that some locations there are spaces before/after commas. Not consistent.

Comment: Valid RGB values are `0-9` and `a-f` or what?

Comment: valid RGBA values are 0 through 255. Thanks

Comment: Maybe `rgb\((\d+,\d+,d+,\d+)\)` would do it in that case. (That's a bit looser than `0-255` but you can change `\d` to a range if that works (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684083/validate-if-input-string-is-a-number-between-0-255-using-regex))

Comment: Loose is fine. But it did not work for me. VSCode search did not recognize any text with that pattern (which I know it should have). Thanks.

Comment: activate the regex search with the `.*` button in the find box

Comment: Regex search is activated :) - but still no luck.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: `rgb\((\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+)\)` works.  Missing a`\\` in @user3783243's regex (3rd number).

Comment: @JackFleeting. It is an XML file.

Comment: I found the issue. In some locations, there were space before/after commas...but the spaces were not consistent. I should have realized that. My bad. With that - I use the expression: `rgb\((.*\d+.*,.*\d+.*,.*\d+.*,.*\d+.*)\)`  and it worked great. I used `rgba($1)` to replace. Thank you everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

To match with any amount of whitespace around the numbers:

```
Search: rgb(?=\((\s*\d+\s*,){3}\s*\d+\s*\))
Replace: rgba
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Search: rgb\(([0-9]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]+)\s*,\s*([0-9]+)\)
Replace: rgba($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

This will match any amount of whitespace and will fix them after replace.