# Regex fails to correctly parse IPv4 inputs

Tags: python, regex, ipv4

I am trying to build an IPv4 regex in Python.  This is what I have:

`r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'`

And these are the inputs it misclassified:

```
Input: "172.316.254.1"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "1.1.1.1a"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "1.23.256.255."
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "64.233.161.00"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "64.00.161.131"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "01.233.161.131"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "1.1.1.1.1"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "1.256.1.1"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "1.256.1.1"
Output: true
Expected Output: false

Input: "255.255.255.255abcdekjhf"
Output: true
Expected Output: false
```

This is the code that I have.  It basically returns a boolean value:

```
import re

def isIPv4Address(inputString):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
    
    return pattern.match(inputString) is not None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failing tests seem to have two causes:

1. Matching first part of string.
2. Not checking number format and value.

### Matching first part of string

The test below fails because the first part of the string (`1.1.1.1`) matches your regex. The additional `a` does not change that:

```
Input: "1.1.1.1a"
Output: true
Expected Output: false
```

This happens because `match` returns an object when the first part of the string matches. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match):

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match this
> regular expression, return a corresponding match object.

Use `fullmatch` if you only want an object when the *whole* string matches. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.fullmatch):

> If the whole string matches this regular expression, return a
> corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match
> the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Alternatively, you can append `$` to your original regex to match the end of line/string. E.g., `r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$'`

### Number format and value

The test below fails because your regex does not check the number's format or value. `\d{1,3}` only checks if there are between 1 and 3 digits. This matches all values from 000 to 0 to 9 to 999.

```
Input: "01.233.161.131"
Output: true
Expected Output: false
```

Checking if the value is within 0 and 255 can be done using a regex, but requires significantly expanding your current regex. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684398/2094999) as an example.

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? I updated my answer regardless.

Comment: I used `fullmatch()` instead of `match()`.  Same problem.  I also appending `$`.  Also did not work.

Comment: Please see the link at the top of this page: your question has been answered before. :)

Comment: First of all, those answers are either important a 3rd party library, which I can't do on a code exercise web app, or they're suggesting what you're suggesting.